# Return statement from a function inside an every iterator block

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

If I am writing a return statement inside of a condition inside an every block - then will it exit the every and return from the function or it will simply act like a return from arrry.map array.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  };

  static getFirstNumberWhichis5(list) {
    list.every((val) => {
      if (val === 5) {
        return 5;
      }
    });
    return 7;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(App.getFirstNumberWhichis5(this.state.list));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I created a code example - and found that it will never return from the function - but what does the return return to - inside an every (or even a forEach for that matter).

Is there any exceptions to the above implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.every` will terminate as soon as the callback returns a `falsey` value, or in your case, if there's no `return` invoked at all, which will happen if the `val === 5` test fails.

Since you don't subsequently test the (boolean) result of the call to `.every` your `getFirstNumberWhichis5` function will always return 7.

Comment: so an every which is not being assigned to a variabl or used anywhere - is useless then.

Comment: technically you _might_ find a use for the callback and its side effects, although best practise for such a callback would be that it doesn't have any side effects.